# Weka Experimenter mod : Problem creating experiment copy to run

Tags: java, weka

In the experimenter mod in weka I have this configuration :

- Results destination : Ex1_1.arff
- Experiment type : cross-validation | number of folds : 10 | Classification
- Dataset : soybean.arff.gz
- Iteration Control : Number of repetitions : 10 | Data sets first
- Algorithms : J48 -C 0.25 -M 2

This experience is saved as Ex1_1.xml (saving with .exp give the following error : Couldn't save experiment file : Ex1_1.exp Reason : java.awt.Component$AccessibleAWTComponent$AccessibleAWTComponentHandler)

And when I try to run this experience I have the following error : Problem creating experiment copy to run: java.awt.Component$AccessibleAWTComponent$AccessibleAWTComponentHandler

So it seem I have a problem with something like AWT in java... Do somebody have an idea ?

Thank you !